# Possible reasons for DC fan failure

Tags: power-supply, fan, interference

In my design I have a constant problem with failing 24VDC fans. The fans are used all across the machine, however they fail in only one position, so I excluded faulty fan model as a source of problem.

The fault: fan does not start by its own means. When pushed with a finger it starts rotating, but slower than normal, and is very easy to stop.

The fan is powered from a stable 24V supply via a relay. Cables from a relay to a fan are approx. 1.5m long, and they share a path with some 230V cables. However, I measured 24V on a fan with a scope, and there are no spikes that could cause the damage.

I have run out of ideas, what causes the problem.

Comment: You haven't told us a whole lot about the ideas you have considered and dismissed. Or the environment : fan orientation, temperature, dirt/dust/oil/other contamination. Or if that fan is building up additional friction (you can feel with the power off) that the others don't.

Comment: Only fail in one position how? One location on the machine? or only when oriented Vertically/Horizontally/Diagonally/etc.  Intake or exhaust? Filters? I'd tend to agree with Brian above and say it is dirt.

Comment: By only one position I meant one location in the machine. There was no dirt or any other contamination on faulty fans, and in some cases their lifetime was only couple of hours. Temperature is around 40-50C, while datasheet says acceptable limit is 70.

Comment: What is the measured voltage across the fan?

Comment: @winny 24V, with spikes up to 27-28V, but only some 1-10us wide, occuring every few seconds.

Comment: @mactro What is the DC voltage measured across the fan when it's not spinning but supposed to?

Comment: Do you have fan part number?

Comment: "_24V, with spikes up to 27-28V, but only some 1-10us wide, occuring every few seconds._" I'd start there. If you're seeing that much noise then the chances are you have bigger spikes that you can't see.

Comment: A thought to ensure you're chasing the right thing (mechanical or electrical issue)... You said it only fails in one position... Can you take the WIRES that drive that magic position, connect them to another fan in the system... And take the wires going to the 'good' fan and connect to the trouble position?   If the failure still occurs in the same position, this might be a mechanical problem.  If the failure follows the driving wires, then look at electrical causes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple of ideas that you could investigate fairly quickly...

(1) The fan is an inductive load being switched by a mechanical relay. Could the fan be generating a back emf that damages the fan on switch on or switch off. You can measure this by putting a DSO across the fan wires, triggering on a positive voltage of 26 V and seeing what happens on relay close/open. This is less likely but quick to test for.

(2) The wiring or crimps are faulty and when the motor pulls its stall current at startup, the drop in the supply gives a voltage too low to drive the fan. This is quick to test for using a multimeter across the fan terminals (right at the fan) when switched on.

Hope this helps, please post any test results.